# How to store <map> in <vector>?

Tags: c++, list, templates, dictionary, stl

need your help.
Lets say that I have 2 classes: `class Category` and `class Product`.

Here its implementation

```
    class Category
    {
        private:
           string _category Name;
           vector<string> _categoryVector;
        public:
           void Add()
           {
            cout << "\n=== ADD <CATEGORY> ===" << endl;
            cout << "\nEnter <Category> Name: ";
            cin >> _categoryName;
            _categoryVector.push_back(_categoryName);
           };
    }
```

---

```
class Product
{
   private:
      string _productName;
      double _productPrice;
      map<string, double> _productMap;
   public:
      void Add()
      {
         cout << "\n=== ADD <PRODUCT> ===" << endl;

         cout <<"\nEnter <Product> Name: ";
         cin >> _productName;
         cout << "\nEnter <Product> Price: ";
         cin >> _productPrice;
         _productMap.insert(pair<string, double>(_productName, _productPrice));         
       };
}
```

---

```
void main()
{
   Category c;
   c.Add();
   c.Add();

   Product p;
   p.Add();
   p.Add();

   system("pause");
}
```

I want to store **Product** in **Category**. To make some logic in this program.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Very confusing. Object of class "Product" contains map of product names to product prices. Object of class "Category" contains vector of category names. Putting one inside other does not add logic to this program.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what you want in your program but
if you just want to store `map` in `vector` Use follow:

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, double> >
```